# Strange key eviction behavior with volatile-ttl

Tags: redis

My use-case is NOT exactly caching. My scenario is a background data analysis service that needs to keep track of some statistics on groups of data, and it's obvious that there will never be enough RAM to keep the statistics of all groups, but we want to keep as many as possible. So with every *n* update of a key, I update the TTL in a way that keys representing more frequent data groups get a higher TTL. The intention is that the most frequent keys will be kept all the time, and only the less frequent/less important ones will be removed.

Here is what I'm doing at the moment:

- `maxmemory` set to a safe value (~40% of RAM because of snapshotting and fragmentation)
- `maxmemory-policy volatile-ttl`
- `maxmemory-samples 100` (I accept a little time lag for this to make sure that I do not lose an important key just because a small sample of only important keys happens to be compared; Redis is not the bottleneck in my scenario)
- The calculated TTL is set with a large offset of 1 week. The idea is that keys will never be evicted just because they have expired, they should only be removed when the memory-limit is reached. So the TTL becomes something like offset + frequency
- My keys are all all sorted sets.

Now, for some workloads, this works perfectly fine. I can see the memory usage increasing near or a little over my memory usage, than staying flat. Less important keys are coming and going, more important ones will stay.

Now I have different workloads, and the key eviction strategy completely fails. E.g. the number of keys goes down to 1/100 of what we saw normally, with only 10% of max-memory in use (double-checked with Redis `info` and on process-level with `top`). The new workload differs in a way that there tend to be less keys but with more updates per sorted set. The maximum number of entries in each sorted set does not differ however, because I have my own pruning for this. The average TTL is shown as 654892235 right now, so around 7.5 days on average, as expected. So the TTLs seem to be fine.

Anything basic I'm missing about how Redis works in this aspect? Are there any other relevant configuration setting? What Redis stats values should I look for to clarify what's going on? Can I configure Redis to log details about each eviction, e. g. the reason, which keys were sampled etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine-grained monitoring (basically dumping all keys every 30s) showed that the workload caused unexpected, enormous spikes in the size of some keys, causing actual low-memory conditions. So the key evictions were absolutely legitimate. After improving my own pruning strategy everything works fine now.

So no problem with Redis itself!